# Pandoc TOC Roman Page Numbers

Tags: pandoc, roman

This is my first question here. Really enjoyed following the exchanges here while writing my thesis, it helped a lot !

I have one problem I could not find a solution anywhere.

My setup is Markdown + pandoc + latex when I can't solve something using the previous two so that pandoc just renders that latex nicely(e.g. tables).

I have a toc defined in the YAML line that works perfectly however I cannot manage to get a roman page numbering on this auto generated toc. I'd prefer not to build a completely new table of content. Is there any magic YAML solution to get these 2 pages with i , ii instead of not numbered ?

Thank you in advance

Strahinja

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. You'll need to give us a little more information about what you're doing. Can you create a small Markdown document that can recreate the problem?

Comment: Most likely you can just put `\frontmatter` before the contents and `\mainmatter` before the beginning of the first chapter.